# Pythonic way to make dictionary within a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a dictionary using the output of a function I wrote (dct) that parses an income and spending .csv file. I designated "amount" as the total of the transaction. dct creates a dictionary that returns this:

```
spending = {
        'month': [],
        'payee': [],
        'amount': [],
        'category': [],
    }
```

The goal of this next function is to make a dictionary that sums all the "amount" outputs per "category" (only car, home, and food). This is my code so far, and it works. Still, I believe is not the most pythonic way to write it. Any ideas?

```
def summarize_by_category(dct):
    car, home, food = 0, 0, 0

    for (index,category) in enumerate( dct['category'] ):
        if "car" in category:
            car += dct['amount'][index]
        elif "food" in category:
            food += dct['amount'][index]
        elif "home" in category:
            home += dct['amount'][index]
    Totals = {
        'car': car,
        'food': food,
        'home': home,
    }
    return (Totals)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what dct would contain?

Comment: Why are you using `in category` instead of `== category`? Can the category be `cars`, `racecar`, etc.?

Comment: Things would be easier if you didn't put categories and amounts in separate lists. Use a list of dictionaries: `[{"category": "car", "amount": 10, "payee": "gas station", "month": "June"}, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how your `dct` is structured - but this might be helpful:

```py
def summarize_by_category(dct):
    Totals = {'car': 0, 'home': 0, 'food': 0}

    for index, category in enumerate( dct['category'] ):
        if "car" in category:
            Totals['car'] += dct['amount'][index]
        elif "food" in category:
            Totals['food'] += dct['amount'][index]
        elif "home" in category:
            Totals['home'] += dct['amount'][index]
    return (Totals)
```

Depending on how your dict is structured, this might work too:

```py
def summarize_by_category(dct):
    return {k: sum(v) for k, v in dct.items()}
```

Comment: `sums` should be `Totals`

Answer (score 2):

Not bad, I would say, but you can make this change:

```
def summarize_by_category(dct):
    Totals = {
        'car': 0,
        'food': 0,
        'home': 0
    }
    for category, amount in zip(dct['category'], dct['amount']):
        for key in Totals:
            if key in category:
                Total[key] += amount
    return (Totals)
```

So,

- You don't reference the list directly. Instead, pair up the amount and cateogry on the fly
- You can have more than three categories without much code change: just add the relevant key to the `Totals` dictionary

Here I assume your category is like "food for John" and "home utilities", if you can do exact match, you should use `==` instead of `in` for faster matching.

Comment: Good idea using `zip` to pair up categories and amounts

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of all the `if/else` if you just use the category as the key in the dictionary.

```
def summarize_by_category(dct):
    totals = {}
    for index, category in enumerate(dct['category']):
        if category in totals:
            totals[category] += dct['amount'][index]
        else:
            totals[category] = dct['amount'][index]
    return totals
```

If you're only interested in some categories, you can initialize the dictionary with those keys, and skip creating new keys.

```
def summarize_by_category(dct):
    totals = {'car': 0, 'home': 0, 'food': 0}
    for index, category in enumerate(dct['category']):
        if category in totals:
            totals[category] += dct['amount'][index]
    return totals
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
def summarize_by_category(dct):
    Totals = {'car': 0, 'home': 0, 'food': 0}

    for i in Totals.keys():
         Totals[i] = sum([dct['amount'][index] for (index,category) in enumerate( dct['category'] ) if i in category ])
    return Totals
```

Or, if you want a shorter way to do it, you could try something like this:

```
def summarize_by_category(dct):
    return {i:sum([dct['amount'][index] for (index,category) in enumerate( dct['category'] ) if i in category ]) for i in 'car,home,food'.split(',')}
```